# c# windows service not firing elapsed event handler

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I have a windows service running 2 timers, one on a 15 minute interval one on 24 hours.
I added event logging to check that the elapsed event handler was firing on the 15 minute one but it doesn't seem to.  Can anyone see anything wrong with this code?

```
public partial class GTstaging : ServiceBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer regularTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        System.Timers.Timer longTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        DateTime _scheduleTime;

        public staging()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _scheduleTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScheduleTime_" + DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()]));
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //** original - ConsoleApplication1.Program.DoProcessing();

            using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
            {
                eventLog.Source = "Application";
                eventLog.WriteEntry("START, regular timer:" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RegularTimer"], EventLogEntryType.Information, 101, 1);
            }

            this.regularTimer.Enabled = true;
            this.regularTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RegularTimer"]);
            this.regularTimer.AutoReset = true;
            this.regularTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.DoRegular);

            this.longTimer.Enabled = true;
            this.longTimer.Interval = _scheduleTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds * 1000;
            this.longTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.DoLongRunning);

        }

        private void DoRegular(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
//do stuff then log
                using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
                {
                    eventLog.Source = "Application";
                    eventLog.WriteEntry("Regular Process End", EventLogEntryType.Information, 101, 1);
                }
        }

        private void DoLongRunning(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            this.regularTimer.Stop();
            this.longTimer.Stop();
            this.regularTimer = null;
            this.longTimer = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the setting of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RegularTimer"]` when you write it to the eventLog?

Comment: I wonder if you tried writing to a file in the `DoRegular` event handler rather than the Event Log. I think you are accessing the log in two different threads (main thread of the service and the timer event handler). So your event may well be firing but you are looking at a false negative because of the logging. [Check this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0680sfkd.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would debug this way:

1. Put a BreakPoint at following line, just to be sure the timers are
   set, then run application in Debug Mode:

   ```
       this.longTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.DoLongRunning);
   ```
2. If previous BreakPoint is reach, set timers interval to 5 and 10
   seconds, just to test they work properly, then run application in
   Debug Mode:

   ```
       this.regularTimer.Interval = 5000; //Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RegularTimer"]);

       this.longTimer.Interval = 10000; //_scheduleTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds * 1000;
   ```

   Then Put a BreakPoint in `DoRegular` method and another in `DoLongRunning` method and run application in Debug Mode
3. If you notice that `DoRegular` method is reached some second after
   `OnStartMethod` and you see that `DoLongRunning` method is reached
   too, we just need to check `this.regularTimer.Interval` and
   `this.longTimer.Interval` are properly set with your original Source
   code.

   You can check their value when `this.longTimer.Elapsed` BreakPoint
   is reach. (Remember the value is expressed as milliseconds)

I hope this way you fix your code, have a nice day!